# Solving an equation with trigonometric and exponential functions

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

While tutoring about integration and derivatives of functions, we needed to determine what the biggest distance between two functions, one trigonometric $f(x)$, the second exponential $h(x)$ for value of $x$ between 0 and 1. For that he had to use his calculator.

But I wondered if one could find it manually, so I derivated the function $d(x) = f(x) - h(x)$ into:

$$d'(x) = 2cos(\pi x)-e^{-2x}+1$$

In order to find out the value where $d'(x)=0$.

My first instinct was to use the formula $cos(\theta)=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$ and then try to solve the equation for $u=e^x$ but then I get the following equation:

$$u^{i\pi}+u^{-i\pi}+u^{-2}+1=0$$

And this is far from the polynomial I used to solve in school. Am I totally off course? Is there no way to solve this manually?

**EDIT:** I already had great answer which pointed me to doing it the numerical way, as it seems that it isn't doable analytically. But was it ever proven that it isn't possible? Or is there simply no known method to this day to do it analytically?

Comment: I'm afraid that an analytical solution might not be available...an Numerical solution is x->-0.3389

Comment: @Harry is it because of the irrational exponents? I also search if one could apply a logarithm on a sum of exponentials but it seemed like a deadend too.

Comment: @Harry note that I am open to any method which isn't "I used a calculator/computer for it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equations which mix polynomial and trigonometric terms do not show analytical solutions (this is already the case for $x=\cos(x)$) and numerical methods are required.

The simplest is probably Newton method : starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$, the method updates it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{F(x_n)}{F'(x_n)}$$ Let me consider the case where $$F(x)= 2\cos(\pi x)-e^{-2x}+1$$ $$F'(x)=2 e^{-2 x}-2 \pi  \sin (\pi  x)$$ and let us use $x_0=\frac 12$. The method generates the following iterates $$x_1=0.613948434899191$$ $$x_2=0.615142392661493$$ $$x_3=0.615143169609597$$ $$x_4=0.615143169609929$$ which is the solution for fifteen significant figures.

The first estimate is already quite good for a manual work.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, has it been proven that it can't be solved anatically, or is there simply no known method?

Comment: This is a good question ! You make me stuck but I am almost sure that there are many proofs of that. I hope you will get answers on that point. Anyhow, when you see mixtures containing polynomial, exponential, trigonometric terms do not waste your time. Go directly to numerical methods. Cheers.

Comment: By the way, such equations are called transcendental equations and this means that !

Comment: You mean all the equations which are composed of a mixture of terms? Or only the ones which aren't analytically solvable? Because I found at least one such equation that I could solve. (If I didn't make any mistake: $cos(ix)-sin(ix)-e^{2x}+1=0$ with $x_1=ln(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})$ and $x_2=ln(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})$)

Answer (score 1):

If you plot $d'(x)$ you will see that it has many zeros. As $e^{-2x}$ is small for large $x$, the zeros will approximate the solutions of $2\cos(\pi x)=-1$ that is
$x_n \approx 2n +\frac{2}{3}\,$ with integer $n$. Examples: For $n=1,2,3,9\;$ you 
get

$$d'(x_1) = -0.0048279499938$$
$$d'(x_2) = -0.0000884269887$$
$$d'(x_3) = -0.0000016195968$$
$$d'(x_9) = -0.6114195798463\times 10^{-16}$$

You can use these approximate zeros and refine them with e.g. Newton iterations.

Comment: I had the feeling that the OP was looking for the solution between $0$ and $1$. For sure, I can be wrong ! Cheers.

Comment: The exercise specified for $x$ between $0$ and $1$, but I was more interested in general answer. Nonetheless, this is a good way to make a first estimate to be able to use in the Newton Method as described by @ClaudeLeibovici.